# Is there any way of checking an instance's references for the Garbage Collector?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I've got a ViewModel class that's not disposing properly. The memory is never freed, even though Dispose is called. I think I'm removing all the references and EventListeners so there's no references to this object - but clearly I haven't go them all because a breakpoint in a temporary destructor is not hit (or just watching the memory usage).

Is there any way I can check with the Garbage Collector if there are any existing references or get any information about them? The class is quite complex, and links up a lot of different models, services etc so it's going to be a lot of work to manually try guess/go through all the code.

There's a bit of confusion. This is a very simple example of how I'm using IDisposable:

```
public class ShortLifecyceViewModel : IDisposable
{
    private LongLifecycleService serviceWithEvent;

    public ShortLifecyceViewModel(LongLifecycleService serviceWithEvent)
    {
        serviceWithEvent.EventTriggered += ServiceWithEvent_EventTriggered;
    }

    private void ServiceWithEvent_EventTriggered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //perform action
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //if this is not called, there is a memory leak. The LongLifecyleService retains a reference to ShortLifecyceViewModel
        //for its "long" life. If this is called, that reference is broken and ShortLifecyceViewModel can be GCed.
        serviceWithEvent.EventTriggered -= ServiceWithEvent_EventTriggered;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** A better solution may be to implement weak event handlers.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into memory profilers (there is a one built into Visual Studio that can analyse memory usage) which should at the very least be able to determine which type(s) are consuming the most memory and also possibly which methods are allocating the most memory. From there you maybe be able to narrow down where the memory leak is coming from.

Comment: Note that nothing you've said definitively indicates a memory leak. Dispose() does not free memory. Further, if you've implemented Dispose() as suggested, you probably won't ever get a call to your finalizer/destructor, either. Beyond that, depending on how you're looking at memory usage, you may not *ever* see a drop in the memory usage of your program. You need to dig into it with a profiler to see if something is actually leaking.

Comment: Disposing of an object has nothing to do with it being released.  Disposal exists to clean up resources not managed by the GC, and has no impact at all on if/when the GC will clean it up.

Comment: @Joe Also, how do you know that it is `not disposing properly`, when by disposing you seems to mean the memory being freed? `The memory is never freed` - what do you use to understand that? GC.GetTotalMemory? Do you force garbage collection? How many times? Do you wait for pending finalizers? Are you sure that there is nothing in your application can allocate more memory during that time? Or do you use WeakReference? Or some external profiler?

Comment: @Servy, Disposing of the object has everything to do with it being released for the reasons you've mentioned. Disposal exists to clean up reasources not managed by GC (in my code I suspect Event Listeners). If I don't dispose these, the references still exist and it is not Garbage Collected. If I have properly removed all the (non circular) references, it will then get Garbage Collected. (That's my understanding anyway!)

Comment: @Martin Costello, I know exactly which types are using the most memory (It's a lot of data for a chart), and which methods allocate it. I also know when it's life-cycle *should* have ended and it should be at least ready to be freed but it appears that's never happening. A memory profilers would just point me at said type. I know the symptom, trying to work out the cause (i.e. why that memory isn't getting freed up).

Comment: @Glorin Oakenfoot, well the memory usage goes up whenever I create one of these view-models and never down when it is disposed. The memory profiler in VS failed to function, the snapshots didn't load. I'll try get it working. Maybe the GC is ignoring these large chunks of data for some reason? I'm getting out of memory exceptions in the application and Visual Studio though.

Comment: @Eugene Podskal When I say not disposing properly, I mean my implementation of IDisposed is not correctly removing all references my class has to longer-lifecycle classes (for example Event subscriptions). I'm presuming this is the reason that these very large classes don't seem to be deconstructed/GCed. I don't expect my implementation of IDisposable to actually free the memory - but it's required for the GC to at some point free the memory.

Comment: I'll add a simplified example of how I'm using it.

Comment: There's no need to remove event handlers in a dispose. An event handler can keep an instance alive as in if you have `publisher.SomeEvent += target.SomeHandler` then `publisher` being uncollectable will mean `target` is uncollectable, but `publisher` will not be prevented from being collected from this, and if it is collectable then `target` will be too (assuming there isn't another live reference). Also you're talking about circular references, which can be an issue with (some) reference-counting garbage collectors, but have no effect on mark-and-sweep collectors like in .NET

Comment: "I mean my implementation of IDisposed is not correctly removing all references my class has to longer-lifecycle classes". Wrong way around. It doesn't matter what references your instance has to anything at all. It matters what references have to it.